# Using JSON to list lookup values on separate lines

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

[image]I currently have the JSON below and want to adapt it so that any multiple values are shown on a separate line, whereas at present each value is separated by ";"

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "white-space": "wrap",
        "width": "100%"
      },
      "txtContent": "=@currentField.lookupValue"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you applying this JSON for main lookup column source or additional/extended lookup columns?

Comment: I will be doing it for three columns ...first one being the main lookup, the second column being an extended lookup column and the third also being an extended lookup column

Comment: WOW Ganesh this is superb and exactly what I needed... very very grateful

Comment: Thanks Ganesh Sanap - MVP.... I applied your suggestion and all is well although the main column no longer seems to launch the hyperlink to the action.... It is just text

Comment: Are you applying it to "main" lookup column or to extended/additional lookup columns?  "Main" lookup columns should be on separate lines by default in SharePoint without applying any JSON (Check the **Before** image in my response below).

Comment: I have applied a screenshot showing where I need some padding added to the JSON on the percentage columns.  Percentage values and Audit Actions arent aligned

Comment: I think you are mixing up conversation in two separate questions and maybe above comment is related to this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310442/padding-needed-to-top-of-sharepoint-online-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For main SharePoint lookup column, you can use the JSON column formatting like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "white-space": "wrap",
        "width": "100%"
      },
      "txtContent": "=replaceAll(@currentField.lookupValue,';','\n')"
    }
  ]
}
```

For extended columns added with SharePoint lookup column, use JSON like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "white-space": "wrap",
        "width": "100%"
      },
      "txtContent": "=replaceAll(@currentField,';','\n')"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint: Replace All Occurrences of Substring in a String using JSON Formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/08/22/sharepoint-replace-all-occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string-using-json-formatting/)

**Output**:

**Before**:

[image]

**After**:

[image]

**Column settings**:

[image]

Comment: # Ganesh Sanap........... wow this is perfect and exactly what I needed, thank you

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!