# Padding needed to top of SharePoint Online field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I' m currently using a SharePoint online modern list.

I have managed to create a lookup column and also a value lookup column

Problem is regarding the JSON formatting. How can I insert a padding value so that the percentages line up with the relevant actions column.

I would also like both the Audit Actions column and Audit Actions; Percentage columns text to be BLUE

[image: Screen Shot]

JSON for Column Called "Audit Actions:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json"
}
```

JSON for Column Called "Audit Actions: Percentage Complete":

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "white-space": "wrap",
        "width": "100%"
      },
      "txtContent": "=replaceAll(@currentField,';','\n')"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add the current JSON you are using for both the columns to your question? You can **Edit** your question add more details.

Comment: JSON for two columns added to the origional question

Comment: Do not add the JSON in comments section as this section has character limit. Instead, **Edit** your original question and add more details.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your JSON code to include padding and color.

Replace `"10px"` and `"blue"` with your desired padding and color values.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "color": "blue",
    "padding-top": "10px",
    "white-space": "wrap",
    "width": "100%"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "=replaceAll(@currentField,';','\n')"
    }
  ]
}
```

Try this and let me know if this works for you.